# Application Authentication Key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, authentication

I have thought of two options for providing an encrypted authentication key for my application and I wanted some feedback from the community to see which option might be best.

Option 1: When they purchase the product they are given a unique ID which they can use to activate the product. During the activation process I send the key to my authentication service and verify it against the order table and then send them back an encrypted key. The encrypted key will contain their original authentication code as well as some other parts which I will add.

Option 2: I do the key encryption on the client side.

I will always need to decrypt the key on the client side as I want to be able to check a couple parts of the key each time the application is run. But should I also do the encrypt there, or on my web service and send it back to the application to store?

Comment: Will the customers that have bought the product always have internet access from the machine they are running it on so that they can always reach you service?

Comment: I am assuming that initial authentication will require an internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

I would opt for option 1 because if the want to add more features to there purchase it sounds like it might be possible for them to re-activate and get a new product key with additional information in it. It will also enable you to have all the logic for key creation and encryption on the server side.